# FAQ link in Historical Lock Notices leads to generic Help Center

Tags: feature-request, bug, historical-lock

The historical lock's FAQ link should probably lead to the page on "on-topicness" rather than just the Help Center in general. I realize that this is probably on the "To Do" list but still figured I'd bring it up anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't done is the close refactor (deployed here on meta) hasn't met with the main branch of help center (everywhere else) just yet...it is on our todo to fix this up.

Also, it's on there because of this post, so thanks! If in doubt, report it!